# override display:block css property of td img

Tags: css

I have following css code  for layout.
td img {display: block;}

While displaying images for gallery, it is creating problem. so i want to remove the code.
But if i remove the code, the full layout breaks.
Is ther any way to override the code , so that display:block doesnt get applied to my gallery's code.?

gallery thumbnails are displayed in table format

sample gallery thumbnail code

thanks in advance for any help or suggestions

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you know the ID of your gallery container, say `#my_gallery`, you can override the CSS just for the gallery:

```
#my_gallery > td img { display: inline; }
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `display:inline;` on the gallery images, which is the default display for images.